# Проблема с прокруткой на странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть у меня временная линия (чем занимался на протяжении нескольких лет. В примере увидите)Когда будете смотреть пример нужно открыть на всю страницу!!!!
Сделал так что в блоке timeline-container при скролле плавно скролило к следуещему блоку.Это должно происходить только в определенном блоке(timeline-container) а дальше должна быть обычная прокрутка на странице.В коде я выделил откуда начинается проблема.Так вот я там написал что `if (num == 7 ){scroll = false;}` Тоесть в блоке timeline-container прокрутка идет плавно от блока к блоку и когда человек прокрутил к последнему блоку и скролит дальше вниз прокрутка на странице стает обычной(если не будет   if num == 7... пользователь  не сможет крутить страницу дальше.Он застрянет в блоке timeline-container)
Моя проблема заключается в том что когда пользователь прокрутил дальше чем timeline-container(ну допустим к самому низу страницы)  и начинает крутить вверх анимация в timeline-container уже не работает (так как scroll = false) и у меня не получается сделать так что бы при прокрутке вверх scroll = true (пишет что scroll не функция).Как сделать при прокрутке вверх анимация вновь работала?

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.timeline = function() {
    var selectors = {
      id: $(this),
      item: $(this).find(".timeline-item"),
      activeClass: "timeline-item--active",
      img: ".timeline__img"
    };
    selectors.item.eq(0).addClass(selectors.activeClass);
    selectors.id.css(
      "background-image",
      "url(" +
      selectors.item
      .first()
      .find(selectors.img)
      .attr("src") +
      ")"
      );
    var itemLength = selectors.item.length;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var max, min;
      var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
      selectors.item.each(function(i) {
        min = $(this).offset().top - 300;
        if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1377px)").matches) {
          min = $(this).offset().top - 150;
        }
        if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {
          min = $(this).offset().top - 300;
        }
        max = $(this).height() + $(this).offset().top ;
        var that = $(this);
        if (i == itemLength - 2 && pos > min + $(this).height() / 2) {
          selectors.item.removeClass(selectors.activeClass);
          selectors.id.css(
            "background-image",
            "url(" +
            selectors.item
            .last()
            .find(selectors.img)
            .attr("src") +
            ")"
            );
          selectors.item.last().addClass(selectors.activeClass);
        } else if (pos <= max - 40 && pos >= min) {
          selectors.id.css(
            "background-image",
            "url(" +
            $(this)
            .find(selectors.img)
            .attr("src") +
            ")"
            );
          selectors.item.removeClass(selectors.activeClass);
          $(this).addClass(selectors.activeClass);
        }
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$("#timeline-1").timeline();


/*  ОСНОВНАЯ ПРОБЛЕМА    */

function slide() {
  h = $(window).height();
  $(".timeline-item").css('height', h);
};



$(".timeline").bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  scroll(event);
});

var num = 1;
var scrolling = false;

function scroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      num--;
      num = num < 1 ? 1 : num;
    } else {
      num++;
      num = num > 7 ? 7 : num;
    }
    if (num == 7){
      scroll = false;
    }

/*   var lastScrollTop = 0;
   $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st < lastScrollTop){   
      scroll = true;
     } 
     lastScrollTop = st;
   });*/

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".num" + num).offset().top -100
    }, 
    500, "linear", function() {
      scrolling = false;
    }); 
  }
}
```

```css
.timeline {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 85%;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline__content-title {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 66px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  transition: .4s;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Pathway Gothic One", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
.timeline__content-desc {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-family: Cardo;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.timeline:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  content: "";
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .timeline:before {
    content: none ;
  }
}
.timeline-item {
  padding: 40px 0;
  opacity: .3;
  filter: blur(2px);
  transition: .5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
.timeline-item:before {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Pathway Gothic One", sans-serif;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: 70%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  right: calc(-100% - 56px);
}
.timeline-item:nth-child(even) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.timeline-item:nth-child(even):before {
  right: auto;
  text-align: right;
  left: calc(-100% - 56px);
  padding-left: 0;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.timeline-item--active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
.timeline-item--active:before {
  top: 50%;
  transition: .3s all .2s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.green{
height:400px;
width:100%;
background:green;
}
.red{
height:400px;
width:100%;
background:red;
}
.timeline-item--active .timeline__content-title {
  margin: -50px 0 20px 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .timeline-item {
    align-self: baseline !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .timeline-item:before {
    left: 10px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    top: 50px;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 60px;
    border: none !important;
  }
  .timeline-item:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
.timeline__img {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.timeline-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 80px 0;
  transition: .3s ease 0s;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.timeline-container:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.8);
  content: "";
}
.timeline-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline-header__title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 76px;
  font-family: Cardo;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}
.demo-footer {
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.demo-footer a {
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Cardo;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .timeline-header__title{
    font-size: 45px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline-container" id="timeline-1">
  <div class="timeline-header">
    <h2 class="timeline-header__title evolvo">ТЕКСТ</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="timeline-item num1" data-text="FATHER OF THE TURKS">
      <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/219998/pexels-photo-219998.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"/>
        <h2 class="timeline__content-title">1881</h2>
        <p class="timeline__content-desc">He was born in 1881 (probably in the spring) in Salonica, then an Ottoman city, now inGreece. His father Ali Riza, a customs official turned lumber merchant, died when Mustafawas still a boy. His mother Zubeyde, adevout and strong-willed woman, raised him and his sister.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item num2" data-text="FATHER OF THE TURKS">
      <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="https://psmag.com/.image/t_share/MTU4MDUzMTI2Mjg3NDAyNTAw/kota_kinabalu_by_dale_preston.jpg"/>
        <h2 class="timeline__content-title">1893</h2>
        <p class="timeline__content-desc">First enrolled in a traditionalreligious school, he soon switched to a modern school. In 1893, he entered a military highschool where his mathematics teacher gave him the second name Kemal (meaning perfection)in recognition of young Mustafa's superior achievement.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item num3" data-text="FATHER OF THE TURKS">
      <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/19400000/rainbow-sky-beautiful-pictures-19401741-1093-614.jpg"/>
        <h2 class="timeline__content-title">1905</h2>
        <p class="timeline__content-desc">In 1905, Mustafa Kemal graduated from the War Academy in Istanbul with the rank of Staff Captain. Posted in Damascus, he started with several colleagues, a clandestinesociety called "Homeland and Freedom" to fight against the Sultan'sdespotism.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item num4" data-text="FATHER OF THE TURKS">
      <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTONrIAFfJBoNIF78x6KgZF5Kk7SLGA0naw3-V1PQx-6wfHxgLK"/>
        <h2 class="timeline__content-title">1908</h2>
        <p class="timeline__content-desc">In 1908 he helped the group of officers who toppled the Sultan. Mustafa Kemal'scareer flourished as he won his heroism in the far corners of the Ottoman Empire,including Albania and Tripoli. He also briefly served as a staff officer in Salonica andIstanbul and as a military attache in Sofia.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item num5" data-text="FATHER OF THE TURKS">
      <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529665253569-6d01c0eaf7b6?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1261d56909dde5237247b6798222337c&w=1000&q=80"/>
        <h2 class="timeline__content-title">1915</h2>
        <p class="timeline__content-desc">In 1915, when Dardanelles campaign was launched, Colonel Mustafa Kemal became anational hero by winning successive victories and finally repelling the invaders.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item num6" data-text="FATHER OF THE TURKS">
      <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/33044/sunflower-sun-summer-yellow.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"/>
        <h2 class="timeline__content-title">1916</h2>
        <p class="timeline__content-desc">Promotedto general in 1916, at age 35, he liberated two major provinces in eastern Turkey thatyear. In the next two years, he served as commander of several Ottoman armies inPalestine, Aleppo, and elsewhere, achieving another major victory by stopping the enemyadvance at Aleppo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item num7" data-text="FATHER OF THE TURKS">
      <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStLCeTfiR_2eiYbRjvyZERQxS8xwn649lxeOksuPuq0TWc_bkn"/>
        <h2 class="timeline__content-title">1919</h2>
        <p class="timeline__content-desc">On May 19, 1919, Mustafa Kemal Pasha landed in the Black Sea port of Samsun to startthe War of Independence. In defiance of the Sultan's government, he rallied a liberationarmy in Anatolia and convened the Congress of Erzurum and Sivas which established thebasis for the new national effort under his leadership.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="demo-footer"><a href="http://www.turkishnews.com/Ataturk/life.htm" target="_blank">Source/Kaynak</a></div>
<div class = "green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Comment: Вы перепутали `scroll` и `scrolling`. Присвоив `scroll = false` вы переопределился свою функцию `scroll` и она, конечно, перестала работать